# How to simultaneously transition colour of nested children

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am struggling to find the CSS that does 2 things, change the colour of all child elements, and do it as a transition. I've created a simple test case of the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr7gvz2f/):

```
<div class="parent">Level 1
  <div>Level 2
    <div class="child">Level 3 (!important means this should become red on hover)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to come up with the CSS to transition the text to a different colour. Here's the skeleton of what I'm working with:

```
.parent {
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
.parent:hover {
  color: red !important;
}
.child {
  color: blue;
}
```

I want to specify a rule at the parent level that will cause all children to change colour. I know using `!important` is discouraged, but this seems like a valid case for using it, as this rule is flagging the section as 'in error' and should override other rules.

Here is what I've done to make it work, but it requires that I have rules for all child elements that set the colour. Which is fine in this simple example, but in the real system poses a problem because we may not know all the rules that change the colour.

```css
div {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-indent: 1rem;
}
.child {
  color: blue;
}

.parent,
.parent .child {
    transition: all 3s;
}

.parent:hover,
.parent:hover .child {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Level 1
  <div>
    Level 2
    <div class="child">
      Level 3 (!important means this should become red on hover)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to transition all the children to a new colour without knowing all classes that must be specified? I tried using a `.parent *` selector, but each level of nesting increases the transition period as in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/savaoxmj/3)

**Update**

I have a better understanding of what's going on. @Hunter resolved the unnecessary `!important` rule. So, the real issue is that the transition-duration property seems to be additive for children, see how slow it takes to remove the red colour when no longer hovering over the text, ideally the colour of each nested element should transition at the same time.

```css
div {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.a-child { color: blue; }

.parent * {
  transition: color 2s;
}

.parent:hover * {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    Level 1
    <div>
      Level 2
      <div>
        Level 3
        <div>
          Level 4
          <div class="a-child">
          Level 5
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want all three levels to change color when someone hovers on the parent element?

Comment: I don't think there is an actual delay in transition. But the delay you see on the element thats blue might be due to it transitioning from blue to red. **Going through intermediary colors.** It might be more visual than a CSS problem. Can't find references though.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange When using the `*` selector, the second bit of text (1st div) is running twice as long on the out transition.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But selectors either match, or they don't. They shouldn't contribute to transition delays. What you are referring to should be the `transition-timing-function` in play. `ease-out`

Comment: @AnkithAmtange I think what is happening is that the nested elements all match the CSS rule, but the transition-duration for each matched rule is additive. So, we see the Level2 colour change take longer than level1 (especially apparent when returning to black)

Comment: @gdros yes, I added an update to clarify that the transitions should run at the same time for all child elements.

Comment: Chiming in here that this is still happening (at least with Chrome) in 2023. One interesting thing to note is that if an explicit initial color it set, the animations work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/ouas4r2v/

Answer (score 7):

The universal selector's performance has improved significantly, but it is still of a concern, albeit a minor one. I'd suggest that you use `.parent div`, if all children are `<div>`s.

CSS:

```
div {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-indent: 1rem;
}

.child {
  color: blue;
}

.parent,
.parent div {
  transition: all 3s;
}

.parent:hover,
.parent:hover div {
  color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  Level 1
  <div>
    Level 2
    <div class="child">
      Level 3 (!important means this should become red on hover)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6j84cb0u/1/).

**edit**

To avoid recursive transation delays just set `color` of black children explicitly, like the blue `.a-child`:

```css
div {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.parent * {
  color: black; /* explicitly set color of children */
  transition: color 2s;
}

.a-child { color: blue; }

.parent:hover * {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    Level 1
    <div>
      Level 2
      <div>
        Level 3
        <div>
          Level 4
          <div class="a-child">
          Level 5
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason for recursive delay, is that `color` property of the parent is set to red until the `transition` is completed then, and only then, `color` value returns to default (inherited from `<body>` i.e. black).

The `color` property of second-level `<div>` is not explicitly set, thus it inherits the value from its parent; that's why it remains red until the `transition` of its parent is completed to inherit the black color, and start transitioning to black, this happens recursively creating the delay effect.

That's why the blue `<div>` starts transitioning instantly to blue when the mouse hovers off; because it has its `color` property explicitly set to `blue`.

Comment: Watch the transition on Level 2, when mouse hover ends we see Level 2 stay red about twice as long as Level 1. So, it seems the transition time is additive, which is not my intent.

Comment: @Josh did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue. My inner text is taking longer to change color than other elements. I've tried many combinations of CSS selectors, Nothing works

Comment: I solved this problem by simply assigning a default color to all text so that it doesn't have to wait for its parent to inherit the color (as conjectured by @5aledmaged ). So I used:
* {
    color: var(--body-text-color);
}
and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

By using the `*` selector and by placing your `.parent` text in a separate div, you can select every child to the parent and apply the transition as well as the color change.

Placing the `.parent` content in a separate div fixes the delay on the out transition.

**CSS**

```
.parent * {
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

.parent:hover * {
  color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>Level 1</div> <!-- <-- Place in div -->
  <div>
    ...
```

By using this, there is also no need for `!important`.

```css
div {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-indent: 1rem;
}
.child {
  color: blue;
}

.parent * {
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

.parent:hover * {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Level 1</div>
  <div>
    Level 2
    <div class="child">
      Level 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr7gvz2f/6/)**

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad to remove the !important rule. However, your change loses the nesting of the divs, so level 1 is a sibling to level 2. If there is nesting we still get the additive delay to the transition, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/gr7gvz2f/7/

Comment: @Josh Since the text belongs to the `.parent` itself, if you wanted you could just use a `<span>` or something instead of a div. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr7gvz2f/8/)

Comment: I revised the question with a better example showing a deeply nested structure. It shows that the deeper the nesting the longer it takes to remove the colour. That is the part that I don't understand, ie. why is there a delay for the transition of nested elements?

Comment: @Josh, thanks for the update. I'll see what I can do.